# ¿Existe una forma de enviar un e-mail sin usar una App en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, c#, email, xamarin.forms

Hace poco que estoy programando en Xamarin.forms y tengo una App que al apretar un botón tiene que enviar un e-mail a un correo predefinido.

Buscando en internet encontré el NuGet `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` El cual funciona, pero eso hace que se abra la App para enviar el correo (Por ejemplo: gmail) y lo que yo necesito es que el correo se envíe directamente sin necesidad de pasar por una App previamente.

¿Existe esa posibilidad?

Aquí dejo lo que hace el botón:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Plugin.Messaging;

namespace PruebaCorreo
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Chat : ContentPage
    {
        public Chat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnMail_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var emailTask = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
            if (emailTask.CanSendEmail)
            {
                // Envia un correo simple.
                emailTask.SendEmail("prueba@test.com", "Asunto", "Cuerpo del mail");

                // Envia un correo con mas datos.
                var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                .To("prueba@test.com")
                .Cc("pruebacopia@test.com")
                .Subject("Asunto del correo")
                .Body("Este es el cuerpo del correo")
                .Build();

                emailTask.SendEmail(email);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera, ahi pones el puerto el mensaje que vas enviar en el correo estos datos son para **gmail**

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail=new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer=new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("El correo del destinatario");
    mail.To.Add("tu dirección de correo");
    mail.Subject = "Asunto";
    mail.Body = "Cuerpo del mensaje";
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials=new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl=true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback=delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        return true;
    };
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Email enviado exitosamente", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}

 catch(Exception ex) 
 {
     Toast.MakeText(Application.Context,ex.ToString(),ToastLength.Long);
 }
```

Comment: Hay algun NuGet que tenga que instalarle? Porque la System.Net que tengo no tiene el Mail para utilizar el SmtpClient

Comment: Si utiliza este System.Net.Http

Comment: Finalmente opté por usar un WebService para enviar el correo porque así lo creyeron conveniente en mi trabajo... igual marco la respuesta porque parece una solucion interesante!

Comment: Q bueno que lograste resolverlo